# What's AWX EE real usage to run ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I installed AWX 19.5 in k8s. I found there are these pods, containers and ee by default:

## Pods

- awx-postgres-0
- awx-8631936913-23hfa
- awx-operator-controller-manager-8631936913-23hfa

## Containers

In awx-8631936913-23hfa:

- awx-web
- awx-task
- awx-ee
- redis

In awx-ee container, I found ansible and ansible-galaxy, etc been installed.

## Execution Environments

- AWX EE (latest) - Image: quay.io/ansible/awx-ee:latest
- Control Plane Execution Environment - Image: quay.io/ansible/awx-ee:latest

---

When run a job template, it seems AWX will create a new pod

```
...
automation-job-11-abcde
```

Even I choose the default AWX EE (latest) as Execution Environment, the same it created new pod then deleted.

So what's the role of awx-ee container in awx-8631936913-23hfa pod? It seems even set ansible configuration and galaxy installation there won't work for jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I also wonder why "awx-ee" and "automation-job" exist at the same time.

"automation-job" actually execute the playbooks. but awx-ee doesn't seem to do anything.

automation-job: created by pulled ee_image. (it could be customized ee_image)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).